# Issue in activity backstack

Tags: android

Activity `A` is the launcher activity. I have a broadcast receiver which receives the incoming message and calls activity `B` (just a popup to display the message).

This is the code I am using to call `B`:

```
intent.setClass(context, popup.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Whenever activity `B` is called, `A` comes behind it (foreground) even if it is in the background. `A` is not called anywhere in the receiver.

How can I call `B` without having `A` displayed behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Activity B needs a different taskAffinity than ActivityA. In your manifest, add this to the ` tag for ActivityB:

```
android:taskAffinity=""
```

When you do what you are doing, when Android wants to start ActivityB, it finds an existing task with the same taskAffinity as ActivityB and it brings that task to the foreground (even though you specified that you want a NEW_TASK). It's a feature, not a bug ;-)